# SMTP Server Mail Alerts using TLS and authentication issue

Tags: email, smtp, tls1.2, smtp-auth, mailx

I am a bit new in using SMTP server Alert configurations on AIX 7.1 OS . I am currently using below syntax which is running fine :

```
mail -s "Subject" "abc@test.com" < /path/to/my/input.txt
```

but we are now migrating our SMTP server with authentication and TLS enable but I am unable to do so. please guide me what am I doing wrong:

```
echo "This is the message body and contains the message" | mailx -v -s "This is the subject" -S smtp=smtp://newsmptp.test.com:25 -S smtp-use-starttls -S smtp-auth=login -S smtp-auth-user="temp" -S smtp-auth-password="Abc#123" -S ssl-verify=ignore "abc@test.com
```

The error I get is:

```
mailx: Not a recognized flag: S
```

Comment: Maybe this question would be a better fit for superuser.com since it seems somewhat system admin related?

Comment: actually i have not used this mailx command that much so i have no clue . need guidance.

Comment: Consulted `man 1 mailx`: indeed, it doesn't have `-S` option. If it were me, I'd start here: https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/aix-sendmail-and-starttls